# C# Check if result from method is null

Tags: c#

```
 string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE name = " + name);
 Database.Insert(sql);
```

How I check if Database.Insert method return null or not

Comment: Did you try writing an `if` statement?

Comment: Maybe operator `==` can help you here?

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: What @SLaks said.  See also: [`SqlCommand.Prepare`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare(v=vs.110).aspx) or other classes that implement `IDbCommand`.

Comment: Also, why are you calling a method called `Insert` with a `SELECT` statement?! That makes literally no sense (unless `Insert` means `Send to database and retrieve the result` which would be ... wierd...)

Comment: what's the status of this question? You neither accepted an answer if it solved the question nor commented under it.

Answer (score 2):

not the best, but the code below will help you check for nulls

```
bool found;

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE name = @name", connection))
{
    connection.Open();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


    if(reader.read())
        found = true
    else
        found = false;

    connection.Close();
}
```